# Java: How to set my codes so that if a userValue does not equal a certain word then it will return back

Tags: java, return

Im trying to get a userValue to return if the userValue does not equal a certain word.  So basically it has to match my word (with is calculus) and if it doesn't then it has to return back to prompt the user to try again.  Im not sure if there is a specific code for this or not.

Sorry i was having trouble uploading my codes, if anyone knows how then please help me.

Comment: The Help Center can _help_ you.

Comment: where can i access that?

Comment: Next to the search bar in the top right corner of the page.

Comment: didn't seem to work, many different links about different things popped up

Comment: @user3357247  You don't "upload" your code, you post it with your question

Comment: it kept saying to format it but i tried and it still didn't work

Comment: @user3357247 You need to read the help. It will only benefit you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is almost certainly to use a loop, the simplest approach would probably be something like -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String toFind = "calculus";
    String word = null;
    // or just ".equals" if it should be case sensitive.
    while (!toFind.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
        if (word != null) {
            System.out.print("Incorrect. ");
        }
        System.out.print("Please guess a word: ");
        System.out.flush();
        if (!scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            break;
        }
        word = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Correct, the word was " + toFind);
}
```